# Can't delete old records from DB in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a code that makes a `ip logs` to DB like this. It should make the log when someone visit a page. The first part of code works and creates logs in my DB.

```py
def ClientIP(request, name="Default Name"):
    try:
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        browser = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    except:
        return
    dt, tm = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d&%H:%M")).split("&")
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    IpLogs.objects.create(
                date = dt,
                time = tm,
                ip = str(ip),
                page_name = str(name),
                browser = str(browser)
            )

    max_date = IpLogs.objects.order_by('-date')[5]
    delete_qs = IpLogs.objects.filter(date__lt=max_date)
    delete_qs.delete()
    return
```

In the last part of the code I'm trying to delete records, that are older than last 5 records. I'm getting this error

```py
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

in this line

```py
delete_qs = IpLogs.objects.filter(date__lt=max_date)
```

My model looks like this

```py
class IpLogs(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    browser = models.CharField(max_length=300)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

local variables are

```
browser 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Safari/537.36')
dt  
'2020-12-18'
ip  
'192.168.71.58'
max_date    
<IpLogs: 192.168.71.58>
name    
'DB tools'
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/'>
tm  
'14:52'
```

What I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max_date is a query set as you define it ... but then you use it in your delete as if it contains an individual date:

```
max_date = IpLogs.objects.order_by('-date')[5]
delete_qs = IpLogs.objects.filter(date__lt=max_date)
```